# Creating MySQL database and user to be hosted on one.com

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to create a MySQL database and administrator user to this database and I intend on hosting the database on one.com. I noticed that in other webhosts e.g. bluehost, the option of creating a MySQL database and a user is available but this is not available on one.com.

My question is how does someone using code create a MySQL database and user which can be hosted on a webhost in my case one.com?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably I didn't get the question. You have to buy a host with MYSQL in it (http://www.one.com/en/product/mysql) and then read the MYSQL and PHP manual for hooking up the two things.

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting providers use CPanel or ZPanel for providing services to their clients. Both the panels come with services that allow creation of a database and assigning an user to the database.

It is possible to query MySQL to do the same, but hosting providers always restricts the clients from direct querying of their database servers.

Comment: Hi aliasm2k, thanks. I'm aware that bluehost utilise the CPanel which is where the MySQL database is created but one.com only have a phpMyAdmin option. Please correct me if I'm wrong but I guess your advice to me is to use code to create a MySQL database and user.

Comment: It is possible to create database using phpMyAdmin. Create a database, check the box to create a user with the same name, and assign privileges to the user and you are done